# not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 1)

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to transform the data values from .csv file to python using sklearn. The problem that I encountered is that it generates this error:

> Exception has occurred: ValueError
> not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 1)

```
data = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/User/Downloads/adult census-1 (1).csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=None) # This is my .csv file dataframe

number = LabelEncoder()
df['workclass'] = number.fit_transform(df['workclass'])
df['education'] = number.fit_transform(df['education'])
df['marital.status'] = number.fit_transform(df['marital.status'])
df['race'] = number.fit_transform(df['race'])
df['sex'] = number.fit_transform(df['sex'])
df['income'] = number.fit_transform(df['income'])

features = ["workclass", "education", "marital.status", "race", "sex"] # Error occurs here
target = "income"

features_train, features_test, target_train, target_test = train_test_split(df[features]),
df[target],

test_size = 0.20,

model = GaussianNB()
model.fit(features_train, target_train)

pred = model.predict(features_test)

accuracy = accuracy_score(target_test, pred)

print (model.predict([[3, 12, 5, 4, 1]]))
```

What is the reason I am getting this error, and how can I fix my code to solve the problem?

Comment: Are you sure the error is occurring on the statement indicated? That is a very unusual error to get when assigning a list of strings to a variable! Also, your call to train_test_split doesn't look right, you end the call statement before specifying what appears to be the target array and test_size parameter.

Comment: show the full traceback error.